# How to debug a WPF vb.NET App crash?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, debugging, crash

I have a long running (kiosk display application) WPF vb.NET App which is crashing after about 15 hours.

I've tested it twice, it's crashed almost at the exact same time.

I have no idea where to start. Any tips?

Thanks
Ben

Comment: First check the event log - does it contain anything related to your app?

Comment: Use WinDBG http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009

Comment: Unfortunately the EventLog isn't showing anything!. I'm currently running the app through WinDBG but I don't really know what I'm doing with it. Thomas - any commands/options you recommend with WinDBG?

Comment: You're not catching exceptions and ignoring them (e.g. with an empty catch block), are you?

Answer (score 2):

Your app might be getting "out of memory". You can watch the memory footprint of you application using Task manager/perfmon or memory profilers to find out if that is the case.